# Class Object update using a form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-word

I am creating a tool in VBA to create labels with information about transactions.

I would like the user to use a form to give all the information and the labels will be automatically created.

To do so I have created a transaction class called `clsTransaction`.

```
Public PartNum As String
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    MsgBox "initialized!"
End Sub
```

At the initilalisation of the form a new object is created

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    (...)

    Dim trans As New clsTransaction

End Sub
```

Then when a textbox is updated, I want to update the object property

```
Private Sub txtPartNum_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strPartNum As String
    strPartNum = txtPartNum.Value
    MsgBox (strPartNum)
    trans.PartNum = strPartNum

End Sub
```

I get the following error message

> Run-time error '424':
>   Object required

My understanding is I need to declare the obect. I have tried to add:

```
dim trans as object
```

but I get an other error message:

> Run time error '91':
>   object variable or With block variable not set

Could someone help me to update the object through the form?

Comment: Which program are using ? Excel ? Access ? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: The dimmed *trans* in `UserForm_Initialize` cannot be 'seen' in `txtPartNum_AfterUpdate` without passing it as a parameter (unlikely) or as a public/private var to that module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the scope of your declaration. By doing this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

(...)

Dim trans As New clsTransaction '<-- declaration + assignment

End Sub
```

you are declaring `trans` in the scope of `UserForm_Initialize()`. Hence, when you then try to do something with it into another scope:

```
Private Sub txtPartNum_AfterUpdate()

(...)
trans.PartNum = strPartNum

End Sub
```

the object `trans` doesn't exist anymore because it's out of scope (so it has already been collected by the garbage collector) and you get an "object required error". You need to declare `trans` at global level, this is the idea:

```
Dim trans as yourClass '<-- global declaration: the object trans will keep on existing into all scopes
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set trans = New yourClass '<-- new instance of the object
End Sub
Private Sub txtPartNum_AfterUpdate()
    'use the instance here
    trans.PartNum = strPartNum
End Sub
```